# how is the esterification of amino acid carried on in this reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, amino-acids, enolate-chemistry, synthesis

i was asked to synthesis this compound from this amino acid, i first alkylated the alpha carbon using enolate alkylating method then i esterficated the amino acid but i'm doubtful that my steps are right, do i need to protect the amino group in the esterification step? or even before ?
[image]

Comment: I don't think your alkene hydration will work on the unprotected amino acid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a protection strategy and there are several choices. This one uses O'Donnell's benzophenone imine strategy [details here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/o-donnell-amino-acid-synthesis.shtm).

First you prepare glycine ethyl ester hydrochloride from glycine with EtOH/HCl, a method is here [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/CN103864632A/en).

From the ethyl ester hydrochloride prepare the benzophenone imine by O'Donnell's method as described in ref 1. This gives a protected species that can be easily alkylated under phase-transfer conditions with allyl bromide as described in ref 1

The allyl product is then epoxidised (MCPBA) and the epoxide opened with iodide [procedure here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja410704d)

Deprotection with acid hydrolysis gives your target molecule.